# configuring zeromq pub/sub with epgm for low latency real-time messages

Tags: udp, zeromq, pgm-protocol

I have searched around a little and understand that unreliable udp unicast is not a supported protocol for zeromq. There is an open issue, [UDP support #807](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/807#issuecomment-151758733), but no real activity on it. So my question is: how can I configure zeromq pub/sub using the epgm (or pgm) protocol to approximate conventional udp unicast performance (and behavior)?

The reason I am asking this question is twofold. First, in my realtime system I am publishing messages at a fairly high rate. If a message is not delivered, re-sending it is worse than dropping it and sending the next one. Second, there are many other use-cases within my system where the zeromq communication patterns apply. Plus, even for this scenario, there are use cases where a conventional zeromq tcp pub/sup is desirable. Using zeromq throughout my system makes a lot of sense, so I would like to use zeromq for this scenario as well without having to roll my own udp implementation. (I am a zeromq newbie and am not a network programming expert, so me adding udp to zeromq is out of scope.)

Since udp is not a current protocol in zeromq, how can I approximate the desired communication by setting the right options for epgm pub/sub?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Your best bet is to take this to the [ZMQ mailing list](http://zeromq.org/docs:mailing-lists) as it deals with low level internals of how the protocols function - my bet is that you won't be able to get what you're looking for over a network, you *may* be able to get it inter-process and inter-thread.

Comment: That said, I could have sworn I'd seen some talk of people using UDP with ZMQ (though I can't remember where, and it may not have been multicast) - however, in your linked open issue, that's Pieter Hintjens responding in the last message, he [wrote the book on ZMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), literally. If he's not aware of it, then it's probably not out there yet - though as you can see, he welcomes anyone to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UDP support got somehow implemented in zeroMQ through new protocols. Refer to the issue you posted.